# Topology continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let X={a,b,c,d} with topology

T={Φ,X,{a},{b},{a,b}, {b,c,d}} and let

F: (X,T) →(X,T) such that

f(a)=f(c)=b, f(b)=d, f(d)=c,

Choose the correct answer:

a) f is discontinuous everywhere.

b) f is not continuous at c.

c) f is not continuous at d.

d) f is continuous on X

Can someone help me solve this question.

If you need any clarification please ask in the comments.

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I tried to find f inverse for every open set in T and check if they belongs to T and concluded that the answer a and d are not correct, but I didn't know how to prove either b or c is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition that f:X -> Y is continuous at x when
for all open V nhood f(x),
exists open U nhood x with
f(U) subset V.

Now check each point, a,b,c,d, and determine if f is continuous at that point.